# Laravel. Сериализация Model::with() или отношений

Tags: laravel, orm

Есть модель Product и связанные с ней разными отношениями модели Category и ProductVariation, которая в свою очередь связана с моделями Image и Property

---

[Структура БД http://freakytools.ru/storage/images/dbdes.png](http://freakytools.ru/storage/images/dbdes.png)

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function variations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductVariation');
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
}


class ProductVariation extends Model
{
    public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image');
    }

    public function properties() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Property');
    }
}
```

---

В Category и Image скрыты все поля кроме name и image_link соответственно. В контроллере я вывожу все Product с зависимостями:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return Product::with(['categories', 'variations', 'variations.images', 'variations.properties'])->get();
    }
}
```

---

В итоге я получаю массив JSON:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Название продукта",
    "description": "Описание продукта",
    "priority": 0,
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "category1"
      },
      {
        "title": "category2"
      }
    ],
    "variations": [
      {
        "slug": "product1_slug",
        "price": 999,
        "count": 99,
        "images": [
          {
            "image_link": "img/products/product1_1.png"
          },
          {
            "image_link": "img/products/product1_2.png"
          },
          {
            "image_link": "img/products/product1_3.png"
          }
        ],
        "properties": [
          {
            "title": "Свойство 1",
            "value": "Значение свойства 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Свойство 2",
            "value": "Значение свойства 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Хочется в полях 'categories' и 'images' получать массив значений, а не объектов с одним-единственным полем. Понимаю, что с этим можно жить. Но нет :D Танцую с бубном вторые сутки. Спасибо за участие!

UPD: Пока реализация такая, но я не хочу верить, что нет более изящного способа решить вопрос

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::with(['categories', 'variations', 'variations.images', 'variations.properties'])->get();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $newCategories = [];
        $newImages = [];
        foreach ($product->categories as $category)
            array_push($newCategories, $category->title);
        foreach ($product->variations as $variation) {
            foreach ($variation->images as $image)
                array_push($newImages, $image->image_link);
            unset($variation->images);
            $variation->images = $newImages;
        }
        unset($product->categories);
        $product->categories = $newCategories;
    }
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: А зачем в category category_id, если там и так есть id?

Comment: А по сути вопроса - так что именно в ответе ждете, кусок переписанного laravel или какой-то нативный способ получить желаемое? Как по мне, так второй вариант нереальный. Да и в чем проблема-то, собственно, ну сделайте фильтр, который ответ будет потом переформатировать по вашим правилам.

Comment: Ну тут только после ->get(), пройтись методами можно, например pluck() или map() преобразовав каждый элемент после выборки, я не думаю что это займет много ресурсов и будет затратно по времени.

Comment: @Станислав в таблице 'categories' же нет category_id? В таблице 'products_categories' category_id для связи "многие ко многим". Или что-то не так?
Хотелось бы решение на уровне функционала самого фреймворка, но т.к. это невозможно, изобрёл костыли.

Comment: @Orange_shadow Спасибо. На основе ваших советов получил результат. Не самое изящное решение, но работает.

Comment: @Freakytools ну насчет того, что чего-либо нет во фреймворке - можете сделать его форк на гитхабе, дописать нужное и сделать пул реквест - возможно, Тейлор согласится его принять, если аргументируете.

Comment: @Freakytools, что же насчет связи, то я не слишком понял, что с чем связываться будет? И кстати если это про вложенность категорий друг в друга, то обратите внимание, что у вас разная длина полей.

Comment: @Станислав, допиливание фреймворков и пулл реквесты это всё же не про меня :) Касательно категорий я, должно быть, ввёл в заблуждение и себя, и Вас самим названием таблицы. Имелось в виду использование тегов для возможности классификации продуктов. Например, нарезной батон можно классифицировать как 'батон', 'из муки высшего сорта', 'с изюмом' и т.п. Соответственно, 'с изюмом' может быть любой другой продукт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете через атрибуты сделать:

```
public function getCategoriesAttribute()
{
    $value = [];
    return Cache::remember('getCategoriesAttribute'. $this->id, 1440, function() use ($value) {
        if($categories = $this->categories){
            foreach($categories as $item){
                $value[] = $item->title;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    });
}
```

Затем вызывать как атрибут, т.е. $product_item->categories

Можно добавить 'categories' в секцию $appends, тогда при любом вызове модели продуктов вам уже будет доступен этот атрибут

Подробнее здесь: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators

Comment: if($categories = $this->categories) - это специально так, или все-таки == нужно? :)

Comment: специально, дабы дважды не дергать вызов связи) проверяется есть ли результат, а затем его перебираем

Comment: @fanamurov Спасибо за решение! Буду иметь его в виду. Отдельная благодарность за подсказку с секцией appends - стало в разы удобнее. Что касается самих массивов однострочных объектов, залез в Illuminate\Support\Collection и добавил метод simplify(), который рекурсивно перебирает текущий объект и упрощает массив однострочных объектов до массива значений. Выглядит опрятно: return $this->categories()->get()->simplify();

Ещё раз спасибо за помощь, проблема решена!